# How do I resolve a 401 error when setting up Juju MAAS environment?

Tags: juju, maas

Here is the debug output:

```
  
2014-01-14 17:09:57 DEBUG juju.environs.configstore disk.go:77 Making /home/neo/.juju/environments
2014-01-14 17:09:57 INFO juju.environs open.go:156 environment info already exists; using New not Prepare
2014-01-14 17:09:57 DEBUG juju.provider.maas environprovider.go:33 opening environment "maas".
2014-01-14 17:09:58 ERROR juju supercommand.go:282 could not access file 'aead8cd6-dc25-4b05-8b31-b7696316546b-provider-state': gomaasapi: got error back from server: 401 UNAUTHORIZED
```

```
ERROR 2014-01-14 11:28:47,651 maasserver ################################ Exception:  ################################
ERROR 2014-01-14 11:28:47,652 maasserver Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in get_response
    response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/decorators/vary.py", line 19, in inner_func
    response = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/piston/resource.py", line 128, in __call__
    actor, anonymous = self.authenticate(request, rm)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/maasserver/api_support.py", line 47, in authenticate
    RestrictedResource, self).authenticate(request, rm)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/piston/resource.py", line 103, in authenticate
    if not authenticator.is_authenticated(request):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/maasserver/api_auth.py", line 57, in is_authenticated
    raise OAuthUnauthorized(error)
OAuthUnauthorized
```

I am trying to connect to my freshly setup maas enviroment. Has anyone else seen this error?

Comment: Did you update your environments.yaml with the maas login credentials?

Comment: Also, can you run bootstrap with `--debug` and `--show-log` flags?

Answer (score 2):

I've actually stumbled upon this error and it was some time ago, but I'm afraid I don't remember the details and the logs AND that version of that maas test server is looong gone.

If memory serves though...I'd go for one of the next 2

1 - "Misconfigured environment" If you tried bootstrapping with a misconfigured yaml with small errors previously and it failed (such as credentials or MaaS IP), then you should delete the environment manually and retry. The file "your_environment.jenv" should be at `~/.juju/environments` . There used to be a bug (or feature) that wouldn't let a new yaml configuration overwrite the old environment, which meant that whatever changes you made to correct it, wouldn't really matter.

2 - Configuration Issue. Unless MaaS is vanilla try running `dpkg-reconfigure` on your maas-cluster-controller & region-controller. On that note...Try talking over plain HTTP. (Adjusting the url in the environments.yaml and the maas url for the cluster & region in the reconfigure window).